# opauth and wordpress facebook auth

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress

Hi i am working on wordpress plugin for facebook authentication by using https://github.com/opauth/opauth but i am facing problem. if you open a link and read documentation. on line 1  Set `DocumentRoot` of your web server to this directory, so that this file is accessible at `http://domainname/README.md` and **not** `http://domainname/example/README.md`. 
but i am having word press files on root so how can i handle this situation

Comment: @mathielo i think he want to ask that wordpress is installed on root directory and this opauth also want to setup in root directory so how one can handle with this situation.

Comment: That's just the example, though. I suspect you'll just need to make sure callback.php is somewhere that opauth can construct an URL to, e.g. put it in your plugin's include directory I think. (But I'm not a WP guru.)

Comment: @Rup callback.php is already there and problem is that i we cant have wordpress and opauth source in root to setup so i need to know if i cant use opauth on wordpress ?

Comment: It's already there in opauth/example, yes, but I'm suggesting if you put it in your plugin includes then it'll be available to be called at the application root inside WordPress (in my limited understanding of WordPress plugins). Is there any reason you can't just put the file in your WordPress root, though - have you tried it? Does that definitely break things? It will be possible to make them co-exist, although I'm not a PHP expert either so I might be missing some of the finer points. If you want an existing WP example that's similar, look at wp-trackback.php: that's effectively a callback.

Comment: @Rup i know i have to put files in plugins folder but as per documentation i have to set this folder as root document but we have worddress installed on root directory so my concern is that is this work or not?

Comment: No, I think you don't need to set that folder as root. You may need to change some paths in the opauth code, but there's no actual requirement for that to be root I don't think other than putting the callback.php in the correct pace.

Comment: I think at this point the best thing for you to do is 1) make example the root and get opauth working 2) try making it not root, then figure out how to get the script working again 3) drop it into your WordPress somewhere, and use what you know so far to make it work in that place.